# Curl a webpage, edit text, then re-open webpage programatically

Tags: java, curl

I am having a bit of a problem. I want to curl a webpage, which is working fine.

```
URL url5 = new URL("put URL here!");

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url5.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
            for (String line5; (line5 = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
               System.out.println(line5);
            }
        }
```

After curling the site, I want to change some values i.e. enter text into a field. After that, I want to click the submit button, then re-curl the new page.

For example, I want to curl the google homepage. I want to programatically enter the text "Today's date". After that, I want to curl the result page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this way. You can use Selenium WebDriver along with HtmlUnit or FireFox to do emulate this behavior.

In Selenium, we create a driver that drives the browser (firefox, chrome, htmlunit etc.). We can perform the operations we want and take screenshots too along the way.

Please read [this](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/selenium-introduction/) article for more information.